# Attribute table disappeared in editing mode in QGIS

Tags: qgis, attribute-table, editing

I have a lot of points, I started to editing with QGIS, after editing my data disappear.

I do not understand the reason?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Are you sure this is the same layer? Which data type does it have? Did you run any operations on it?

Comment: Yes is the same layer, I move the point, save the layer,  and after all my data are deleted

Comment: Can you provide example data?

Comment: Yes, where I send the shapefile ?

Comment: Please upload it and add a link to your question.

Comment: https://files.fm/u/c2wwjj7qv

Comment: It simply looks as if you don't have any attributes. If you had them before, could it be you deleted them?

Comment: The DBF file is corrupted, it can't even be opened in Excel/LibreOffice.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As @JGH pointed out, part of the problem may be that your DBF file is corrupted, and it is.

I opened the dbf in a hex editor and some bytes needed to read it are missing. The bytes 8(08) through 10(0B) were zeroed, these bytes tell you how big is the file header and how big are the records in bytes. Your first byte value is a zero too, which is a valid value from [the spec](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.dbf) (as far as I can tell) but doesn't seem to open unless it is a `0x03` value, similar to other shapefiles.

What you had:

[image: Incorrect header]

What it should be:

[image: Correct Values]

I corrected the values and now your shapefile works in QGIS, and the values remain when in edit mode.

Here is a archive with a working shapefile, hopefully 10 minutes of my work saved you having to recreate 2055 records.  Enjoy.

https://drive.protonmail.com/urls/FTS6NAKZX0#hFewF3y3nmA6

Comment: WOW! This is fantastic, real magic. This is definitely on of my prefered answers. Reallly great.

Comment: Many thanks, you are realy good !!!!!!!

Answer (score 1):

The cause of file corruption is the storage point of file I worked in pgcloud. Many thanks for support !!