# Adding vector shapefile with all elements to QGIS V 3.16 not recognized data source

Tags: qgis, shapefile, vector, data-source

I am trying to add a vector shapefile to QGIS V 3.16 and am receiving an error message "Not a valid or recognized data source". There is nothing wrong with the file connection on my end as far as I can see and I have all the correct elements (shp, dbf, shx) in the folder. I have tried with and without the .inf file and tried to do a zip file and nothing is working. Does anyone know how I might troubleshoot?

I created the shapefile in pathfinder from trimble data collection

Files here: https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/19jwy79-CPG1Fqouj5V8kfhDuBGjZNp5g?usp=sharing

Comment: Ask the provider to check, whether the data is faulty or not.

Comment: Probably the error already occured when you created the shapefile. Normally, the `shp` file (containing the actual data) is the largest of all, but in this case, it is not. Check out your original data source.

Comment: Thank you! It should be bigger than the dbf? I'll check with the source.

Comment: It may be bigger but it depends on the data. Shp stores the geometries, dbf stores the attributes.

Comment: Yep it definitely is corrupted, specifically I think the DBF file is corrupted - opening it in a text editor just shows a whole lot of NULLs and not a single bit of actual data (which is not expected). Opening it in a hex editor shows 00s everywhere so there is just nothing in the file

Comment: Maybe this helps? https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/419154/88814

Answer (score 1):

GDAL does not open the file but it does not show any error messages. OpenJUMP gives an error `Negative Array Size Exception`. ArcGIS Pro behaves like GDAL, no messages. It seems that your shapefile is definitely corrupted.