# How to open shapefiles in QGIS

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system, shapefile, file-geodatabase

Trying to open/add .shp file of wetlands delineation. QGIS error stating something like "invalid file type". Tried several times... through data mgr. Add vector layer. That's #1 problem...#2 is the .shp isn't in any crs, or georeferenced.
If #1 can be cured, is there a preferred method for the latter?

Comment: With your Shp, how many files are there? Is there any chance that when copying the Shp a file or two was left behind?

Comment: As Keegan said. A shape file is not a file but a file set. You need at least *.shp, *.shx and *.dbf, there.may also be a few other files, such as a *.prj file for projection information, but if any of the three first are absent, the shape 'file' won't work.

Comment: And if you should have all the files and it still does not work, can you upload them somewhere so that somebody else can test them. Also nice if you can describe how you got the files.

Comment: Please edit the question and add the exact error message. This will probably help someone pinpoint the problem.

Answer (score 1):

To assign the correct CRS to a layer, use `Right click / Layer / Layer CRS / Set Layer CRS`. However, you have to know in which CRS the layer was created. And: the setting of the CRS will not be saved to the file, but will be active only for the current project.

Comment: I'm fairly squared away with CRS's. The .shp file problem is the more pressing issue.

Comment: OK, you stated "If #1 can be cured, is there a preferred method for the latter?" - so I understaood that the CRS problem is your main question. For the shp file problem, I guess no one can help without additional information. But have a look here: https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/419154/88814

Comment: If you set a CRS on a file, I guess you can export it to get a new file (or file set in  the case of shp) with CRS information